# react useEffect fetch - TypeError?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, fetch-api, use-effect

What is wront with this code..

on console everything work but after i try fetch data to div using `setData(result)`
I have big fat error:

```
×
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setData is not a function
(anonymous function)
C:/blog/src/components/BlogPosts.js:19
  16 |        .then((res) => res.json())
  17 |        .then((result) => {
  18 |          console.log(result)
> 19 |          setData(result)
     | ^  20 |        })
  21 |    }
  22 |
```

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import styles from './BlogPosts.module.css'


const BlogPosts = () => {
  const { data, setData } = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result)
          setData(result)
        })
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <section className={styles.posts}>
      {/* <div>
        {data.map((x) => {
          return <div key={x.id}>{x.title}</div>
        })}
      </div> */}
    </section>
  )
}

export default BlogPosts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here lies the problem:

```
  const { data, setData } = useState()
```

useState( ) hook returns an array so you should be destructuring an array instead

```
  const [ data, setData ] = useState()
```

P.S, doesn't hurt to initialise the state as an empty array (compared to nothing / undefined, which it is right now)

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState([])
```

You're doing this because down in the code you commented out, you're trying to use the map() method, which is a method of arrays.

Comment: You're right, I had to remove it - but even with [] the code doesn't work

Comment: I have made a demo of working code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-carson-ix3n8?file=/src/App.js:442-548). Check if what you've done matches it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const fetchData = async () => {
      let res = null;
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result)
          res = result;
        })
      return await res;
    }
useEffect(async() => {
   const data = await fetchData();
   setData(data);
  }, [])
```

Comment: Can you please use above solution with const [ data, setData ] = useState([]) state destructuring.